# Using MCT twice to show the limit of an integral depending on $x$ and $n$

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

So I have $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{n^2}_0 e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) dx$. I'd like to apply the MCT but the trouble is there is a limit which also depends on $n$

So I thought let's do :$\displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty}\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{m^2}_0 e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \,dx$.

First deal with $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{m^2}_0 e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)\, dx$ (This is all in my Lebesgue Integration course by the way.)

For this I want to let $f_n=e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n= x e^{-x^2}=f$ if you think about limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ being $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$- that limit should be simple to get. I want to find an upper bound for all the $|f_n|$ -$g(x)$ which is INDEPENDENT of $n$ and apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem so I realised $ne^{-x^2}$ would not work. $f_n$ is not montonically increasing in $n$ so Monotone Convergence theorem I doubt will work. However I plan to use MCT on another sequence $h_m=h\chi_{[0,m^2]}$ where h is the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{m^2}_0 e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \,dx$. I can see none rigorously that $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-m^2})$ will come out of first integral which is positive for large enough $m$ so we MCT which only works for non negative functions.

EDIT:Actually wait after that we dont get any integral or anything to do with $x$ we just consider $\displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty}$ $\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-m^2})$
and the limit of that is $\frac{1}{2}$ so yup the only problem is DCT at the start then... Could anybody please help?

Edit: Or am I going about this the completely wrong way...

Comment: The very first step is (very!) wrong! You cannot take iterative limits just because you don't want $n$ to appear as an extreme of integration, that radically changes the problem you're trying to solve! For example you can't do $$\lim _{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n = \lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^m = 1$$ which is of course wrong as the correct limit is $e$

Comment: @MichaelHardy- Why'd do you delete it?

Comment: @Ant wonderful ok I understand

Comment: @Arcane1729 : I wanted to separate the part of the domain within which I knew that that sequence increases with $n$ from the part where the value of the sine may be negative. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)\cdot \chi_{[0,n^2]}(x)$.

On the interval $[0,1]$, this is a monotone increasing sequence of functions, and MCT can be applied.

On the interval $[1,\infty)$, you have

$$
\int^{n^2}_1 e^{-x^2} n \sin\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \, dx = \int\limits_{[1,\infty)} f_n(x)\,dx
$$

and

$$
|f_n(x)| \le xe^{-x^2}
$$
and
$$
\int\limits_{[1,\infty)} xe^{-x^2} \, dx < \infty
$$
so the dominated convergence theorem can be applied.

I'm not at all sure this is the simplest way, but it should work.

Comment: please give me time to digest before I accept- I'm in particular to trying to figure out why it's monotone in $[0,1]$

Comment: $$ n\sin\frac x n = x\cdot \frac{\sin(x/n)}{x/n} = x \cdot \frac{\sin u} u$$ That this increases with $n$ is the same as saying $(\sin u)/u$ increases as $u\to0$ for $u$ close enough to $0$. $\qquad$

Comment: My worry is that it's not non-negative on $[0,1]$ which prevents using MCT

Comment: Woops there we're thinking about $n$ fixed and $x$ in $[0,1]$- nope I'm fine with that

Comment: Ah for some reason I didn't realise that $n\sin(\frac{x}{n})$ was bounded- so the whole thing was... I think also you may have meant that it was bounded by $xe^{-x^2}$ perhaps? Not sure if it's me who's wrong here- but other than that much obliged :) time to accept

Comment: @MichaelHardy Michael, this is the usual way forward - so +1!  There is a typographical error; an omitted $x$.  $|f_n(x)|\le xe^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @ MichaelHardy : no need for the dominated convergence theorem. your argument on $[0,1]$ works for $[0,m]$ whenever $n > \pi m/2$ (or something like that). and the residual $\int_{C n}^\infty f_n(x) dx \to 0$ without any problem  ( @Dr.MV )